# How can I append data to the HTML table result from the API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, append

I have an endpoint request that brings data back in an HTML table.

```
var row = document.createElement('tr');
          var cell = document.createElement('td');
          cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rowData['description']));
          row.appendChild(cell);
```

The table populates with the data from the endpoint, but I would like to add additional bits to this data rather than just the description from the API endpoint.

Comment: `cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'Your Prepended Verbiage | ' + rowData['description'] + ' | Your Appended Verbiage' ) );`  ??

Comment: Hello! Thank you @Zak!

I used an ID, but the table just updated with raw text rather than an image.

So, it worked, but not in the way I would like

( 'https://image.subdomain' + rowData['ID'] + '.com' );

Any idea how to use the ID in an image?